# by changing dataframe some columns are duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataset:

```
,target,text
0,0,awww thats bummer shoulda got david carr third day
1,0,upset cant update facebook texting might cry result school today also blah
2,0,dived many times ball managed save 50 rest go bounds
3,0,whole body feels itchy like fire
4,0,behaving im mad cant see
5,0,whole crew
6,0,need hug
```

I wanted to separate my csv and bring all data whoch has target = 0 to another `.csv`

```
data_neg = df['target'] == '0'
df_neg = df[data_neg]
df_neg.to_csv("negative.csv")
```

And aftrer doing this column in `negative.csv` which has no name is duplicated:

```
,Unnamed: 0,target,text
0,0,0,awww thats bummer shoulda got david carr third day
1,1,0,upset cant update facebook texting might cry result school today also blah
2,2,0,dived many times ball managed save 50 rest go bounds
3,3,0,whole body feels itchy like fire
4,4,0,behaving im mad cant see
5,5,0,whole crew
```

why it happens and how to avoid duplicating it? it only happens with the first column with `id`

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy and specify which column is your index when reading the CSV file:

```
# ... 

df_neg = df[data_neg].copy()
df_neg.to_csv("negative.csv")


# For reading it
df_neg = pd.read_csv("negative.csv", index_col=0)
```

Comment: but I still have duplicated column in .csv

Comment: You shouldn't unless `df` has the duplicated, can show the output of `df.columns`? also when reading the data for `df` specify the `index_col` parameter, as the problem can be related to `df` and not `df_neg`

Comment: I just found out that each csv,not also these in exaples after someoperations on them (like etracting rows to another file nad so on) make one more column with `id` . is this also happens by working with pandas `csv` or it is just problem of my IDE? i work with `sPYder`

Comment: Remember, every time you read a CSV, there should be one column o be treated as the index if the index is not on your CSV or you don't specify int, then pandas will assign an integer starting from 0 per row. You can also save your CSV files without the index column. Check whenever you read a CSV, what are the columns on your dataframe and if they match what you are expecting.